# selected columns must appear in GROUP BY clause error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a SQL query to get the month end prices for a particular instrument.

Table (contains some other columns that can be ignored):

| instrumentId | unitPrice | reportedAt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 90.22 | 2018-10-28 |
| 1 | 80.55 | 2018-10-30 |
| 1 | 70.55 | 2018-09-15 |
| 1 | 70.56 | 2018-09-23 |

Expected result:

| instrumentId | unitPrice | reportedAt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 80.55 | 2018-10-30 |
| 1 | 70.56 | 2018-09-23 |

There will be multiple rows for the same `instrumentId` with different `reportedAt` from different months. The idea is for each month and year (e.g. Oct 2018), I am trying to get only the last price `reportedAt` for each month.

```
SELECT 
    "instrumentId",
    "unitPrice",
    MAX("reportedAt") as reportedAt
FROM 
    "InstrumentPrice"
WHERE 
    "instrumentId" = 90
GROUP BY 
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "reportedAt"),
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "reportedAt")
ORDER BY 
    "reportedAt" DESC
```

However, this query keeps throwing an error saying the columns selected must appear in `GROUP BY` clause or be used in an aggregate function.

This will not work because if I group by `unitPrice` or `reportedAt`, I will not get the desired results (because they are all unique).

Comment: window functions will be better for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your query is caused by including the column `unitPrice` and `instrumentId` in the `SELECT` clause without including it in an aggregate function or in the `GROUP BY` clause.

In SQL, when you use `GROUP BY`, you should either:

- Include the column in the GROUP BY clause.
- Use an aggregate function (like MAX, MIN, SUM, etc.) on the column in the SELECT clause.

---

You can achieve this using window functions. You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to assign a row number to each row within each month and year partition based on the `reportedAt` column, and then filter for rows where the row number is 1 (indicating the last price reported for each month). Here's how you can do it:

```sql
SELECT
    "instrumentId",
    "unitPrice",
    "reportedAt"
FROM (
    SELECT
        "instrumentId",
        "unitPrice",
        "reportedAt",
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "instrumentId", EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "reportedAt"), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "reportedAt") ORDER BY "reportedAt" DESC) AS row_num
    FROM
        "InstrumentPrice"
    WHERE
        "instrumentId" = 90
) subquery
WHERE
    row_num = 1
ORDER BY
    "reportedAt" DESC;
```

In this query:

1. The inner subquery assigns a row number to each row within each month and year partition using the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function. The `PARTITION BY` clause partitions the data by `instrumentId`, month, and year, and orders the rows within each partition by `reportedAt` in descending order.
2. The outer query then selects rows where the row number is 1, which corresponds to the last price reported for each month and year combination.

Answer (score 1):

`group by` is not the right tool for your job. Here it is using window function `row_number()`.

```sql
with t as
(
 select 
   instrumentId, unitPrice, reportedAt,
   row_number() over (
                      partition by date_trunc('month', reportedAt)
                      order by reportedAt desc
                     ) as rn
 from the_table
)
select instrumentId, unitPrice, reportedAt
from t where rn = 1;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tTZor5TedHow3EAjnoEhMf/1)